# Ruby HTTP proxy chaining

Tags: ruby, proxy

Is it possible to route HTTP(S) traffic through two proxies with ruby?

```
Our Workers <> Our Gateway Proxy <Given IP> Third Party Proxies <> Target # How?
```

We are using third party proxy servers and some of them use IP-based authentication. As we have multiple worker instances, and these get more over time, we would like to set up an anonymising proxy server with a given IP to route our traffic to the third party proxies.

Right now we are using `Net::HTTP::Proxy(...).start`.

If that matters, we don't want to rout all our traffic through that proxy, not to create a bottle-neck. Just those which require a specific IP address.

Comment: Did you figure this one out?

Comment: No, I have not. Sorry.